# Query not using indexes -

Tags: database, performance, oracle, sqlplus

Is there any way I can use index on REFERENCETYPE column.Below is the table structure and execution plan.

```
SQL> desc messaginginbox
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------
 MESSAGINGINBOXID                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)
 REFERENCEID                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)
 REFERENCETYPE                                      VARCHAR2(1)
 LISTINGID                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)
 CREATEDATE                                         DATE
 LASTUPDATED                               NOT NULL DATE
 UPDATEDBY                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)
 RENTERLISTINGMANAGERID                             VARCHAR2(28)
 OWNERLISTINGMANAGERID                              VARCHAR2(28)
 OCA                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(38)

SQL> create index idx_MESSAGINGIN_REFERENCE on MESSAGINGINBOX( REFERENCETYPE);
Index created.

SQL> analyze table MESSAGINGINBOX compute statistics;

Table analyzed.

SQL> select * from MESSAGINGINBOX where referencetype='B';

55 rows selected.

Execution Plan
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                | 71354 |     9M|   873   (1)|
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MESSAGINGINBOX | 71354 |     9M|   873   (1)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> create bitmap index idx_MESSAGINGIN_REFERENCE
     on MESSAGINGINBOX( REFERENCETYPE);

Index created.

SQL> analyze table MESSAGINGINBOX compute statistics;

Table analyzed.

SQL> select * from MESSAGINGINBOX where referencetype='B';

55 rows selected.

Execution Plan
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                | 71354 |     9M|   873   (1)|
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MESSAGINGINBOX | 71354 |     9M|   873   (1)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> select count(*) from MESSAGINGINBOX;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    142707

SQL> select distinct referencetype from MESSAGINGINBOX;

REFERENCETYPE
-------------
I             
B       

SQL> select count(distinct referencetype) from MESSAGINGINBOX;

COUNT(DISTINCTREFERENCETYPE)
----------------------------
                   2
```

Comment: Can you run `select referenceType, count(*) from MessageInbox group by referenceType;`?  Currently Oracle assumes that half of the values are "B", and half are "I".  If that's accurate, then you likely do not want to use an index.  If that's inaccurate, first try replacing `analyze table` with `begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(<schema>, 'MESSAGINGINBOX'); end;`.  Also, if you set the column ReferenceType to `NOT NULL`, that would enable Oracle to use the index in more situations.

Comment: Thanks Jonearles, It worked for me, I used DBMS_STATS view to gather the statistics. BitMap index is working efficiently here. Count for I= 142652 and B are only 55. I want to know if there is any alternative of BitMap index. The reason behind asking this question is, I need to execute this query on different machine where we are using standard Edition which does not allow to use BitMap indexes.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to take advantage of the fact that an index will not include entries where the full set of columns is NULL - i.e. create a function-based index that only indexes the 'B' records:

```
CREATE INDEX just_the_Bs ON messaginginbox
  (CASE WHEN referencetype='B' THEN 'B' END);
```

To use the index, however, you have to query using the same expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM messaginginbox
WHERE (CASE WHEN referencetype='B' THEN 'B' END) = 'B';
```

I would expect this to most likely use an index range scan followed by table lookup by rowid, given the relatively small volume of data which matches this predicate.

Another way is to use a hint - but note that you may need to add more hints (such as `USE_NL`) in order to avoid some very poor execution plans:

```
SELECT /*+INDEX(messaginginbox,idx_MESSAGINGIN_REFERENCE)*/ *
FROM messaginginbox WHERE referencetype='B';
```

In particular, note the advice here on hints - it can take a lot of hints to force the CBO to use a particular plan: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/how-to-hint/

Answer (score 0):

A regular Btree index should work here, you just need to ensure there is a [histogram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/stats.htm#i42219) on the ReferenceType column.

The column data is skewed, and the optimizer appears to know that.  It correctly estimates the distinct count as 2, which is why the rows estimate is almost exactly the number of rows divided by 2.  With the default settings, Oracle creates histograms based on the data distribution and how the columns are used.

Replace the deprecated `analyze table` with `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` and be sure to use all the default options.  You also need to run a query filtering on ReferenceType BEFORE you gather stats.  By default, Oracle will not create a histogram if the column hasn't been used in a predicate.

Run this query to see if the histogram is generated:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, histogram
from all_tab_columns
where table_name= 'MESSAGINGINBOX';
```

A histogram should at least improve the estimated cardinality (rows), which is the first step to fixing an execution plan.